# R loop xts plots

Tags: r, loops, plot, xts

I am stuck on what is probably a simple problem: Loop on xts objects.

I would like to make four different plots for the elements in the basket: `basket <- cbind(AAPLG, GEG, SPYG, WMTG)`

```
> head(basket)
           new.close new.close.1 new.close.2 new.close.3
2000-01-04 1.0000000   1.0000000   1.0000000   1.0000000
2000-01-05 1.0146341   0.9982639   1.0017889   0.9766755
2000-01-06 0.9268293   1.0115972   0.9856887   0.9903592
2000-01-07 0.9707317   1.0507639   1.0429338   1.0651532
2000-01-10 0.9536585   1.0503472   1.0465116   1.0457161
2000-01-11 0.9048780   1.0520833   1.0339893   1.0301664
```

This is my idea so far, as I cannot simply put in i as column name:

```
   tickers <- c("AAPLG", "GEG", "SPYG", "WMTG")

par(mfrow=c(2,2))    
for (i in 1:4){
    print(plot(x = basket[, [i]], xlab = "Time", ylab = "Cumulative Return",
         main = "Cumulative Returns", ylim = c(0.0, 3.5), major.ticks= "years",
         minor.ticks = FALSE, col = "red"))
    }
```

This is the error I get when running the script:

```
Error: unexpected ',' in "     main = "Cumulative Returns","
>      minor.ticks = FALSE, col = "red"))
Error: unexpected ',' in "     minor.ticks = FALSE,"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I have added the error I get when running the script.

Comment: Try remove brackets around `i`. Can you `dput` your data for [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1422451)?

Comment: Well that was actually it. Removing the brackets from the i gave me four charts. Not the most beautiful ones as the ylim should be very different for each plot it seems... Thank you though. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, remove the square brackets around `i`:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))    
for (i in 1:4){
    print(plot(x = basket[, i], xlab = "Time", ylab = "Cumulative Return",
         main = "Cumulative Returns", ylim = c(0.0, 3.5), major.ticks= "years",
         minor.ticks = FALSE, col = "red"))
}
```

But even better, assign names with `cbind` in building `xts` object or re-name your `xts` object like any data frame, then iterate across names for column referencing and titles:

**Plot**

```
# PASS NAMES WITH cbind
basket <- cbind(AAPLG=APPLG, GEG=GEG, SPYG=SPYG, WMTG=WMTG)

# RENAME AFTER cbind
# basket <- cbind(AAPLG, GEG, SPYG, WMTG)
# colnames(basket) <- c("AAPLG", "GEG", "SPYG", "WMTG")

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
sapply(names(basket), function(col)
  print(plot(x = basket[, col], xlab = "Time", ylab = "Cumulative Return", data = basket,
             main = paste(col, "Cumulative Returns"), ylim = c(0.0, 3.5), 
             major.ticks= "years", minor.ticks = FALSE, col = "red"))
)
```

[image: Plot Output]